# Does slf4j support all features of log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, java.util.logging

does slf4j support all/most features of log4j? What happens if I use slf4j with java.util.logging and try to use a feature that only log4j has, but which java.util.logging does not have?

Best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

slf4j is just a facade, an interface between many different loggers and your code. The idea is to have an abstraction layer between your code and the logger you decide to use in your deployed application.

You use slf4j to send your logging event to the chosen loggers, but the configuration itself is at the logger's level.

*Does slf4j support all/most features of log4j?*

That's not the intended purpose. It doesn't provide any feature at all, just the facade.

*What happens if I use slf4j with java.util.logging and try to use a feature that only log4j has, but which java.util.logging does not have?*

Just use and hit log4j under slf4j, this is how you are supposed to do it anyway.

slf4j will want a logger below its facade, you can use java.util.logging, or you can use log4j itself, no problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I meant was: Does slf4j offer access to all/most features of log4j or more general: Intends slf4j to offer access just to the features all logging frameworks have in common or does it intend to offer access to any feature of any supported framework? My second question aims at the last case and I just want to get a rough idea. I cannot test myself yet, because I have no experience.

Comment: slf4j provides only access to log.debug(), log.trace(), log.info(), log.warn(), and log.error() . And a factory to create the logger object. That's all. http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link!